# Find who stopped the service

Tags: java, linux, service

My application is installed on a customer linux machine as a service.
From time to time he complains that the application stops.
The thing is that I can see from my application logs that the service is stopped gracefully (not crashed), but he's saying he didn't stopped it.
How can I tell who caused my service to stop?
My application listen to a configured port via socket, if someone writes to this socket - the application stops.
The customer say that there's no automated process that might cause the service to stop.

Comment: Can you check the IP address and see if it matches to the customers?

Answer (score 3):

If it is an actual graceful shutdown, the culprit can be found by looking in the history.  If it's the fault of the system, you should be able to correlate the time stamp of your application shutdown, with an event in the sys logs.  If it's caused by something external, you might want to increase your logging on incoming connections.

Comment: what do you mean by looking in the history? which history?

Comment: the console history on the linux machine

Comment: thanks. how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of some extreme resource starvation. Ask your client if he is running out of RAM and swap space.

Comment: Thanks. In such case, I would expect killing the process? because I can see in my logs graceful shutdown.

Comment: This is probably true. It probably wouldn't be a graceful shutdown, but I'm not 100% sure.